# Installing GWT M2E Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, m2e

I'm new to Eclipse (currently I use EE Helios SR 1). I get the following when I try to install GWT M2E:

> Missing requirement: m2e connector for gwt 0.0.1.0 (com.levigo.m2e.gwt
>   0.0.1.0) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.7.1' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>
> From: GWT M2E Connector 0.0.1.0
>   (com.levigo.m2e.gwt.feature.feature.group 0.0.1.0)
>
> To: com.levigo.m2e.gwt [0.0.1.0]

What exactly should I look for in the marketplace? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new to eclipse. Do you really want this plugin? It's a plugin that `Manages Supersource and Resource Folders for GWT-Projects`: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-m2e/. But it's for use with maven projects. If you want a plugin for GWT in eclipse you should have the official eclipse plugin: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll install the plugin for GWT.